# Microphone treated as line-in is heavily distorted

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

I want to mix the audio output of a console with the audio on Windows so that I can play games and watch videos/talk via VOIP programs while also hearing the game audio. To do this, I have bought a HDMI-repeater that extracts audio to RCA and an additional soundcard. The RCA output is converted to a regular 3.5mm audio jack that's plugged into the soundcard's microphone input. In Windows, I've set it to listen to this device.

This setup works, but the audio from the device is heavily distorted, even with microphone boost disabled. Feeding the RCA into a pair of headphones directly yields the expected audio, so there is no problem with the repeater.

Does Windows treat microphone input in some specific way that result in these distortions, and can they be disabled? The audio card I use is an ASUS Xonar DGX, and aside from changing the input volume (distorted on all volume levels) and toggling microphone boost, I can't seem to improve the audio.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you use line-in instead of mic socket? Have you tried? Is the result the same?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the mic and line-in shares an input, but the modes can be toggled in the audio card software; something I missed. Thank you.

Comment: Using the line-in mode fixes the distortions.

Answer (score 1):

The ASUS Xonar DGX shares a port of the microphone and line-in. Selecting the line-in mode under the "Mixer" category and instead listening to this device with Windows fixes the distortion issue.